# Sampling distribution of unbiased estimator

Tags: self-study, sampling, skewness, unbiased-estimator

> Is the sampling distribution of an unbiased estimator symmetrically centered around the true value of the parameter? Why? Why not?

Intuitively I think the question above is true (since I can use the approximation to a Normal Distribution) but I suppose there could be a counterexample.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Your intuition proceeds from fallacious reasoning: you thought about an example that would fit the conditions and so concluded that the proposition would be true, but if that worked, this would be correct reasoning: "*I say it is a fact that all dogs have exactly three legs. Here is a dog with three legs. Therefore the proposition is true*". Hopefully you see the flaw there. This is a form of the anecdotal fallacy. See also [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias),  and the [availability heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Availability_heuristic) ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... if you want to consider examples it is more productive to search for counterexamples than confirming examples. If you can find even *one* counterexample you have disproved the claim. By contrast, a hundred confirming examples proves only that it's not *always* false. So your interest should have focused on estimators whose sampling distribution was asymmetric and then tried see if you could find any that were unbiased (of which elementary examples abound)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its false, consider $X_1,\dots,X_n \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$

Then $\bar{X}$ is unbiased for $\lambda$, but $\bar{X}\sim \frac{1}{n}\cdot\text{Poisson}(n\lambda)$, and the Poisson is a right skewed distribution.(Of course, the 1/n just scales the distribution, it doesn't change the skew.)